# unable to aggregate and group by on one particular field

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm trying to find `$avg` of some values but the `aggregate` and `$group` isn't doing what I expect.

First, I confirm I have some test records as follows:

```
db.reportgraphs.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd922edcec85b1b8ea7749b"), "lId" : ObjectId("5fd922ed4d25ab1bb975f117"), "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4"), "d" : ISODate("2020-12-15T20:56:13.412Z"), "vs" : 113.3, "vi" : 127.9, "c" : 0, "tc" : 30, "td" : 28, "ts" : 33, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd922edcec85b1b8ea774a2"), "cId" : 6, "lId" : ObjectId("5fd922ed4d25ab1bb975f117"), "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4"), "d" : ISODate("2020-12-15T20:56:13.412Z"), "vs" : 14.168, "ts" : 24, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd922edcec85b1b8ea7749f"), "cId" : 3, "lId" : ObjectId("5fd922ed4d25ab1bb975f117"), "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4"), "d" : ISODate("2020-12-15T20:56:13.412Z"), "vs" : 14.173, "ts" : 23, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd922edcec85b1b8ea774a0"), "cId" : 4, "lId" : ObjectId("5fd922ed4d25ab1bb975f117"), "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4"), "d" : ISODate("2020-12-15T20:56:13.412Z"), "vs" : 14.155, "ts" : 24, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd922edcec85b1b8ea7749c"), "cId" : 0, "lId" : ObjectId("5fd922ed4d25ab1bb975f117"), "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4"), "d" : ISODate("2020-12-15T20:56:13.412Z"), "vs" : 14.183, "ts" : 24, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd922edcec85b1b8ea774a1"), "cId" : 5, "lId" : ObjectId("5fd922ed4d25ab1bb975f117"), "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4"), "d" : ISODate("2020-12-15T20:56:13.412Z"), "vs" : 14.177, "ts" : 24, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd922edcec85b1b8ea7749e"), "cId" : 2, "lId" : ObjectId("5fd922ed4d25ab1bb975f117"), "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4"), "d" : ISODate("2020-12-15T20:56:13.412Z"), "vs" : 14.176, "ts" : 24, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd922edcec85b1b8ea7749d"), "cId" : 1, "lId" : ObjectId("5fd922ed4d25ab1bb975f117"), "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4"), "d" : ISODate("2020-12-15T20:56:13.412Z"), "vs" : 14.187, "ts" : 24, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd922edcec85b1b8ea774a3"), "cId" : 7, "lId" : ObjectId("5fd922ed4d25ab1bb975f117"), "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4"), "d" : ISODate("2020-12-15T20:56:13.412Z"), "vs" : 14.173, "ts" : 25, "__v" : 0 }
```

Notice how eight of the records has a `cId` and one record does not have a `cId`.  I want to do the mongo equivalent of

```
SELECT bId, cId, AVG(ts), AVG(tc), AVG(td), AVG(vi), AVG(vs), AVG(c) FROM reportgraphs GROUP BY year, month, day, hour, minute, bId, cId
```

So I tried this command:

```
db.reportgraphs.aggregate([
{
  $match:{
    d:{$gte:new Date("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt:new Date()},
    bId: ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4")
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    bId: 1,
    cId: 1,
    yr:{"$year":"$d"},
    mt:{"$month":"$d"},
    dy:{"$dayOfMonth":"$d"},
    h:{"$hour":"$d"},
    m:{"$minute":"$d"},
    vs:1,
    vi:1,
    c:1,
    tc:1,
    td:1,
    ts:1,
  }
},
{ $unwind: "$vs" },
{ $unwind: "$vi" },
{ $unwind: "$c" },
{ $unwind: "$tc" },
{ $unwind: "$td" },
{ $unwind: "$ts" },
{
  $group: {
    "_id": {"yr": "$yr", "mt": "$mt", "dy": "$dy", "h": "$h", "m": "$m", "bId": "$bId", "cId": "$cId"},
    "vs": { "$avg": "$vs"},
    "vi": { "$avg": "$vi"},
    "c": { "$avg": "$c"},
    "tc": { "$avg": "$tc"},
    "td": { "$avg": "$td"},
    "ts": { "$avg": "$ts"},
  },
},
]);
```

But this yielded only one result:

```
{ "_id" : { "yr" : 2020, "mt" : 12, "dy" : 15, "h" : 20, "m" : 56, "bId" : ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4") }, "vs" : 113.3, "vi" : 127.9, "c" : 0, "tc" : 30, "td" : 28, "ts" : 33 }
```

I was expecting nine results, one for each `cId` based on the records I showed initially.  What did I do wrong?

---

WEIRD

Also note that the `cId` isn't even appearing in my final result. Why is that so?

Comment: Ah i see, it's not necessary...I understood what `$unwind` does after reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448175/whats-the-unwind-operator-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it short and simple:

```
db.reportgraphs.aggregate([
{
  $match:{
    d:{$gte:new Date("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt:new Date()},
    bId: ObjectId("5fc151b2c123574e0f835da4")
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    yr:{"$year":"$d"},
    mt:{"$month":"$d"},
    dy:{"$dayOfMonth":"$d"},
    h:{"$hour":"$d"},
    m:{"$minute":"$d"},
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    "_id": {"yr": "$yr", "mt": "$mt", "dy": "$dy", "h": "$h", "m": "$m", "bId": "$bId", "cId": "$cId"},
    "vs": { "$avg": "$vs"},
    "vi": { "$avg": "$vi"},
    "c": { "$avg": "$c"},
    "tc": { "$avg": "$tc"},
    "td": { "$avg": "$td"},
    "ts": { "$avg": "$ts"},
  },
},
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You unwind on several fields that are not in there - default with unwind is to not include anything if the array is empty or not an array. You can ask it to include the record with

```
$unwind:
    {
      path: "$vi",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
```

in your case you don't have any arrays but if you did have some optional ones in these fields that needed unwinding if they were there make sure you add this.

Comment: makes sense now, the `$unwind` does something like an `INNER JOIN`, so joining on nulls/empties will cause things to go away.  Adding the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` is almost like a `LEFT JOIN`.  Or I just avoid using `$unwind` in my scenario because i don't have array of elements to join on.

Comment: `$unwind` on a non-array field is pointless anyway.